# not able to position text over image in a flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I'm trying to position some text to the bottom right corner of an image that's in a flex layout. It doesn't seem to be working. I'm very new to flex and am making a lot of mistakes. I have a left column and a right column, both of which contact 6 rows of 2 images. In the middle I have some explanatory text. I want the numbers 1 through 12 to be superimposed on the lower right corner of each image.

html:

```
<div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="flexbox-2col-container">
        <div class="column50perc"><img src="img/20171118ng_Akasha L Van-Cartier5 1.JPG" />
        <div class="number">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column50perc"><img src="img/20171118ng_Akasha L Van-Cartier5 1.JPG" /></div>
        <div class="column50perc"><img src="img/20171118ng_Akasha L Van-Cartier5 1.JPG" /></div>
        <div class="column50perc"><img src="img/20171118ng_Akasha L Van-Cartier5 1.JPG" /></div>
        <div class="column50perc"><img src="img/20171118ng_Akasha L Van-Cartier5 1.JPG" /></div>
        <div class="column50perc"><img src="img/20171118ng_Akasha L Van-Cartier5 1.JPG" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox-1widecol-container">
        <div class="middle"><h3>12 people to meet in 2018</h3></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox-2col-container">
        <div class="column50perc"><img src="img/20171118ng_Akasha L Van-Cartier5 1.JPG" /></div>
        <div class="column50perc"><img src="img/20171118ng_Akasha L Van-Cartier5 1.JPG" /></div>
        <div class="column50perc"><img src="img/20171118ng_Akasha L Van-Cartier5 1.JPG" /></div>
        <div class="column50perc"><img src="img/20171118ng_Akasha L Van-Cartier5 1.JPG" /></div>
        <div class="column50perc"><img src="img/20171118ng_Akasha L Van-Cartier5 1.JPG" /></div>
        <div class="column50perc"><img src="img/20171118ng_Akasha L Van-Cartier5 1.JPG" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.flexbox-container {
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        flex-direction:row;
        align-items:stretch;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .flexbox-2col-container {
        flex: 2;
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        flex-direction:row;
        align-items:stretch;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .flexbox-1widecol-container {
        flex: 1;

        padding: 10px;

    }
        h3 {
            font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
            font-weight: 600;

        }
    .column50perc {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    img {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        display:block;
    }
    img:hover {

    }
    .middle {

    }
    .middle h3 {
        background-color: #404040;
        color: white;
    }
    .number {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        z-index: 2;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **absolute** position so you should make the parent element **relative** position. Like that each box will be positioned relatively to his container and thus correctly positioned on the image:

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flexbox-2col-container {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flexbox-1widecol-container {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.column50perc {
  padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

img:hover {}

.middle {}

.middle h3 {
  background-color: #404040;
  color: white;
}

.number {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="flexbox-2col-container">
    <div class="column50perc"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
      <div class="number">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column50perc"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
      <div class="number">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column50perc"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
      <div class="number">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column50perc"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" /></div>
    <div class="column50perc"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" /></div>
    <div class="column50perc"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox-1widecol-container">
    <div class="middle">
      <h3>12 people to meet in 2018</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox-2col-container">
    <div class="column50perc"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" /></div>
    <div class="column50perc"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" /></div>
    <div class="column50perc"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" /></div>
    <div class="column50perc"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" /></div>
    <div class="column50perc"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" /></div>
    <div class="column50perc"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```